# Twitter Bootstrap in Firefox Extension

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, firefox-addon

When I use Bootstrap to make a style in my extension in Firefox, the style is applying to browser's style. How to fix it?

with Bootstrap
[image: with Bootstrap]

without Bootstrap
[image: without Bootstrap]

Comment: You really have to give more information about what styles you are using and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding the bootstrap CSS via an overlay to `browser.xul` itself. The bootstrap styles and rules will clash with the `browser.xul` styles. That is not supported.

You're free to use bootstrap in own (add-on) webpages, and maybe even windows, but you cannot use it in overlays.